# overlapping div using minus margin only show text

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs wrapped inside a div (slide).
I would like the lap div to appear inside of wall div. I tried adding minus top-margin to lap div, but it only shows the text 'hello' and I can't see the background.

```
<div class="slide">

    <div id="wall"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mGjd59Z.png"/></div>
    <div id="lap">hello</div>
  </div>


#lap {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #F34245;
    margin-top:-60px;
}
```

[jsfiddle reference](https://jsfiddle.net/nn16d6aL/)

expected result

[image]

but the this is what I'm getting. i'm asking why only text appear ?if lap div goes underneath of wall div  ,then why text appear??

[image]

---

edit

I was able to fix the problem with @Alon answer, but there is a question.

**if lap div goes underneath of the wall, then why does the text appear?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `transform:translateY(-60px);` instead of `margin-top:-60px;`

Or use z-index to make it appear above:

```
#lap {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #F34245;
margin-top:-60px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

About your question (if lap div go to underneath of wall ,then why text appear??) I've noticed that if you add `position:relative` to `#wall` then the text doesn't appear so it might have something to do with positioning, but again, I'm not sure why this behavior is like that.

Comment: ok thanks .it really works but why??is it wrong to give minus margin for my requirement  ?

Comment: @FastSnail Nothing wrong with that, I updated my answer to match your attempt with the minus margin top

Comment: `z-index: 1;`  doesn't work .i think because it's not absolutly positioned

Comment: @FastSnail It does. when you add `position:relative;`

Comment: ohh sry i though it only work for absolute .but i have just one question .if lap div go to underneath of wall ,then why text appear??

Comment: @FastSnail Interesting question, unfortunately I don't know the answer

Comment: @nevermind image isn't transparent.i just checked with different image but issue is same

Comment: @FastSnail Keep this question open ".if lap div go to underneath of wall ,then why text appear??" Let's see if anyone has any answer for it. Or open a new question with it, just to know the behaviour.

Comment: @Dipak - I added more details to this answer, hope it will help